# Plotting Pandas Data

Tags: python, pandas

I'm a little confused as to what the `spx = data['SPX']` line does in the following code:

```
from datetime import datetime
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)
data = pd.read_csv('ch08/spx.csv', index_col=0, parse_dates=True)
spx = data['SPX']
spx.plot(ax=ax, style='k-')
crisis_data = [
(datetime(2007, 10, 11), 'Peak of bull market'),
(datetime(2008, 3, 12), 'Bear Stearns Fails'),
(datetime(2008, 9, 15), 'Lehman Bankruptcy')
]
for date, label in crisis_data:
ax.annotate(label, xy=(date, spx.asof(date) + 50),
xytext=(date, spx.asof(date) + 200),
arrowprops=dict(facecolor='black'),
horizontalalignment='left', verticalalignment='top')
# Zoom in on 2007-2010
ax.set_xlim(['1/1/2007', '1/1/2011'])
ax.set_ylim([600, 1800])
ax.set_title('Important dates in 2008-2009 financial crisis')
```

Comment: Oh never mind, I think i figured it out. I'm assuming its referring to the column that's being used?

Comment: Yep, that extracts the column with the name "SPX"

Answer (score -1):

it extracts the column with the header saying `SPX` from the csv file.